# Extjs store find all

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Documentation of `Ext.data.Store` find method says:

> Finds the index of the first matching Record in this store by a
>   specific field value.

My question is how can I find indexes of all matching records in this store?

Comment: the ExtJS version would be helpful

Answer (score 10):

I think the best function met your needs is `queryBy()` because it returns array of matched Records.

You still can use `each()` to check if the Model matches the criteria then add them to an array. But this function is more appropriate to traversing all Records in the store, not just for "filtering" data.

Comment: The [`query` method](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-query) also provides a shortcut version of `queryBy`.

Answer (score 1):

Extjs store have few methods which return first matched record by a specific field value. To get all filtered records you have to use **each** function && than match or filter the desired records.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ExtJS 3.x, assuming you have your data store referenced by `store`

```
Ext.pluck(store.filter('field', 'value'), 'id');
```

returns an array containing the indexes of the matching records.

Comment: from 4.x `filter()` does no longer return anything. Also `Ext.pluck` will be found under Ext.Array.pluck. The other point is that the store is filtered after that.

Comment: As you commented, the ExtJS version would be helpful. My answer is correct for ExtJS 3.4